# Simplifcation of the Function Required

Tags: combinatorics, approximation, factorial, approximation-theory

I want to simplify the following expression

$$
\sum_{x=0}^{D+m} \frac {x!} {(n+1)_x} (\frac {\theta_{eff}} {\mu})^x {D+m \choose x}
$$

The parameters $D, m, n, \theta_{eff}, \mu, $ are constants.
Can anybody help me in approximating the expression?

Regards